# Create 2d list from 1d list with given length and width?

Tags: python, list, 2d

How to create 2D list from 1D list with given row and cols?

Given:

```
sample_list=[5, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 1, 6, 7, 2, 3]

row=2
cols=4
```

It should return this:

```
[[5, 2, 3, 4],[1, 6, 1, 6]]
```

I don't need other numbers = 7, 2, 3.
I just want a list that has row and cols which user gives.
My solution does not return what i want,

My solution:

```
def 1D_to_2D(sample_list, row, cols):
    return [sample_list[i:i+cols] for i in range(0, len(sample_list), rows)]
```

returns:

```
[[5, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 1, 6], [1, 6, 1, 6], [1, 6, 7, 2], [7, 2, 3], [3]]
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just slice your list using a list comprehension with `range` and a step of `cols` (not `rows` as you used), and limit the number of items using external slicing with `rows`:

```
sample_list=[5, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 1, 6, 7, 2, 3]
rows=2
cols=4

result = [sample_list[x:x+cols] for x in range(0,len(sample_list),cols)][:rows]
```

result:

```
[[5, 2, 3, 4], [1, 6, 1, 6]]
```

Comment: yes. but the accepted answer doesn't truncate the list, it just stops at the right moment, so it's slightly better (well, could have done with some more explanation, code is not all!)

Comment: note that I wasn't saying that to get answer acceptance from you.

Comment: (note that we're the 2 ones upvoting the other answer :))

Answer (score 1):

```
def D_to_2D(sample_list, rows, cols):
    return [sample_list[cols*i: cols*(i+1)] for i in range(rows)]

>>> D_to_2D([5, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 1, 6, 7, 2, 3], 2, 4)
[[5, 2, 3, 4], [1, 6, 1, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f = lambda x, row, cols: [x[i:i+cols] for i in range(0, cols*row, cols)]
f(x, row, cols)
```

Comment: What does this return? I think some context for your answer would be in place here

Comment: It returns the intended answer